# Changing startDate and endDate params of BootStrap Datepicker on change of a select Box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

What I am trying to do :

I am trying to set the startDate and endDate params depending on the current value of year.
I think that currenty what I have just sets the params onLoad, however I need to know if there is a way which can enable me to trigger the updation of startDate / endDate Params on some event

Here is the code :

html :

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="2012-2013">2012-2013</option>
    <option value="2012-2013">2013-2014</option>
    <option value="2012-2013">2015-2016</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myStartDate" placeholder="dd-mon-yyyy" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy" readonly="readonly">
```

js :

```
var myStartDt = $('#myStartDate')
    .datepicker({
    startDate: getStartDate(),
    endDate: getEndDate()

}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {

    myStartDt.hide();
}).data('datepicker');

function getStartDate() {
    var f = $('#mySelect').val().split('-');
    return '01/04/' + f[0];
}

function getEndDate() {
    var f = $('#mySelect').val().split('-');
    alert(f);
    return '31/03/' + f[1];
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fRzyL/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the values of `option` **2013-2014 and 2015-2016** like

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="2012-2013">2012-2013</option>
    <option value="2013-2014">2013-2014</option>
    <option value="2015-2016">2015-2016</option>
</select>
```

Change this to **js**,

```
var myStartDt;
function mydatepicker(){
   myStartDt= $('#myStartDate')
        .datepicker({
        startDate: getStartDate(),
        endDate: getEndDate()
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        myStartDt.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
}
 $("#mySelect").on('change',function(){
    // alert(this.value)
    $('#myStartDate').datepicker("remove");
    mydatepicker();//$('#id-element').datepicker("destroy");
});
mydatepicker();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fRzyL/2/)

Comment: does not work, already tried that before. I think that when the page loads, the datepicker gets the values from getStartDate and getEndDate functions and set it as params (only once). As a result, no matter what option I choose, it will show dates for 2012-2013

Comment: Nope. Same as before.

Answer (score 24):

I think you can simply use `setStartDate` and `setEndDate` methods: http://jsfiddle.net/ivkremer/fRzyL/21/

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I don't see anywhere else on the interwebs where it states you have to access the datepicker object via data().

Comment: Even though this works perfectly. For me I could set the start/end date once while loading the page, but changes weren't applied later on. Using this method however does allow dynamically updating the start/end date.