# Bootstrap datepicker date range from and to

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I have a problem related to bootstrap3 datepicker, this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(
    /* This is the function for multi datepicker */
    function () {
        $(document).on('focus',".datepickers", function(){
            $("#searchByCreateDate").datepicker({
                endDate : new Date(), 
                beforeShow : function()
                {
                    $(this).datepicker({maxDate: 0});
                },
                autoclose:true,
                altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            });
            $("#searchByToDate").datepicker({
                endDate : new Date(), 
                beforeShow : function()
                {
                    $(this).datepicker('option','startDate', $('#searchByCreateDate').val() );
                }, 
                altFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                autoclose:true
             });
         }); 
    }
);
```

I have two datepickers - one for `from date` and second for `to date`. My requirement is when user selects `from date` then `to date` starts with `from date` and previous dates are hidden and in `to date` user can only select next three months in single time.

Comment: please reword your question. It's really really hard to read and understand what exactly you need

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `startDate` and `endDate` to your datepicker. As you don't know the needed dates beforehand, you have to add them when first is chosen - `onChange`. You should add this..

```
$('#searchByCreateDate').on("change", function(){
   //when chosen from_date, the end date can be from that point forward
   var startVal = $('#searchByCreateDate').val();
   $('#searchByToDate').data('datepicker').setStartDate(startVal);
});
$('#searchByToDate').on("change", function(){
   //when chosen end_date, start can go just up until that point
   var endVal = $('#searchByToDate').val();
   $('#searchByCreateDate').data('datepicker').setEndDate(endVal );
});
```

Info taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269813/changing-startdate-and-enddate-params-of-bootstrap-datepicker-on-change-of-a-sel).

Comment: because they are executed right when your page is loaded. Thus your input fields are empty and restrictions are not set. that `datepicker` constructor is executed only once. it doesn't work 'live' listening to fields all the time.

Comment: you can't. You have to add these `onchange` listeners, that I have in my answer. That code listens to when elements are changed and edits your datepickers. you can add these lines at the end of document.ready and it should work.

Comment: this works fine, but still has an issue that is the event keeps looping

Comment: this could help

.on("change", function(e){
      var endVal = $(this).val();
    
      if($(this).val()!="" && getFormattedDate($('#workFromDate').data('datepicker').getEndDate())!= endVal)
        $('#workFromDate').data('datepicker').setEndDate(endVal);
    });

Comment: This snippet does exactly what it should do. it's odd that it isn't marked as the correct answer